# Jquery sorting html table rows by date

Tags: jquery, html

I have been using a script to sort tables by a date string which I got from stackoverflow but the code has stopped working. May I kindly ask if anybody knows why?

```js
$('tr.Entries').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
    t = this.cells[1].textContent.split('-');
  $this.data('_ts', new Date(t[2], t[1] - 1, t[0]).getTime());
}).sort(function(a, b) {
  return $(a).data('_ts') > $(b).data('_ts');
}).appendTo('tbody');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table-bordered" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr class="Headers">
      <th>Number</th>
      <th>Date start
      </th>
      <th>Date end</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="Entries" data-id="13">
      <td data-field-type="string">1234</td>
      <td data-field-type="date">01-04-2015</td>
      <td data-field-type="date">01-04-2015</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Entries" data-id="24">
      <td data-field-type="string">1352</td>
      <td data-field-type="date">04-10-2012</td>
      <td data-field-type="date">23-10-2015</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Entries" data-id="8">
      <td data-field-type="string">1124</td>
      <td data-field-type="date">13-05-2014</td>
      <td data-field-type="date">01-04-2015</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Entries" data-id="23">
      <td data-field-type="string">1652</td>
      <td data-field-type="date">07-11-2013</td>
      <td data-field-type="date">22-10-2015</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Entries" data-id="23">
      <td data-field-type="string">1652</td>
      <td data-field-type="date">04-12-2013</td>
      <td data-field-type="date">22-10-2015</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Your code works perfectly, check your fiddle, and tell us what are you getting exactly? How it isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

The `compareFunction` passed to `sort` needs to return an integer, if `<` is used, it's returning a boolean. The documentation mentions:

> - If compareFunction(a, b) is less than 0, sort a to an index lower than b, i.e. a comes first.
> - If compareFunction(a, b) returns 0, leave a and b unchanged with respect to each other, but sorted with respect to all different elements.
> - If compareFunction(a, b) is greater than 0, sort b to an index lower than a, i.e. b comes first.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

The change needed is replace `$(a).data('_ts') < $(b).data('_ts')` with `$(a).data('_ts') - $(b).data('_ts')` or `$(b).data('_ts') - $(a).data('_ts')` depending on the order you want.

Comment: This is not the real problem, it's also working with `>` or `<`, check [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rmva17gr/530/).

Comment: I see the same result on that fiddle.
If `<` is changed to `-` the rows will be sorted by the value on first column .

Comment: What you stated about `compareFunction` callback is correct, **but** it's not the case here, It's working with `<` and `>` there's no need to use `-`, the code is already working, check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rmva17gr/531/).

Comment: It's using `this.cells[1]` the second column, that has dates, just by looking at the year they don't seem sorted (2015, 2012, 2014, 2013, 2013) the same order as the original html code.

Comment: Thank you kindly rvazquezglez, works perfectly by replacing $(a).data('_ts') < $(b).data('_ts') with $(a).data('_ts') - $(b).data('_ts')